# update from 12.04 to 14.04, cron stops working

Tags: 14.04, cron

I am having trouble of using cron after updating from 12.04 to 14.04.

here is my log:

```
May  8 11:00:01 imanqasrina CRON[30716]: (sicksand) CMD (bash $HOME/bingwallpaper/bingPaper_v1-0.sh)
May  8 11:00:01 imanqasrina CRON[30717]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/flexget --cron)
May  8 11:05:01 imanqasrina CRON[31963]: (sicksand) CMD (/usr/bin/notify-send "notify from cron")
```

and here is my crontab -l

```
#min hour mday month wday command
0 11 * * * bash $HOME/bingwallpaper/bingPaper_v1-0.sh
5 * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "notify from cron"
```

Answer (score 0):

The system log shows that the command is running, but the log may not contain errors. You can capture stdout and stderr by adding a MAILTO to your crontab:

MAILTO=sicksand

Of course the first test is to run the command manually just as shown in the log.